# Почему выскочит Exception?

Tags: java, сериализация

```
import java.io.*;

public class Hotel implements Serializable {
    private Room room = new Room();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hotel h = new Hotel();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Hotel.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(h);
            oos.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Room {
}
```

Comment: `class Room` не имплиментит `Serializable`, поэтому и выскочит `java.io.NotSerializableException`